# Sqlite file copy while launching Application

Tags: ios, core-data

How to store database from one sqlite file (which is in our bundle) to sqlite file (which is created while we using core data) while we launching application first time.

Should we copy each entity, each row in loop or Is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put sqlite file directly in your bundle, for example you can create sqlite file with SQLite manager in firefox. Then when start your app you can check if file exist in the document directory, if not you need to create it. This only the first time.